# Can evil Buu return to Dragon Ball Super?

Tags: character, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

In DBZ Buu saga, we were introduced to 2 Buus, **Evil** and **Good** Buu. But it was also showed that Good(*fat*) Buu is good because he had absorbed [Grand Supreme Kai](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Supreme_Kai) and his innocence is what made Buu good. But inherently, both are same beings.

Now in Dragon Ball Super, we were showed how much Buu loves fighting and trained so hard to get in shape for the Tournament.

So my question is, can this desire negate the good Grand Supreme kai had on Buu and bring his evil self back?

Negate may be incorrect term so I'll try to explain. This desire may give rise to some evil in Buu and this evil part goes to Buu's mind(*We have seen this as well in Buu Saga*) and breaks connection with the cocoon in which Grand Supreme Kai is held.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the bad part of buu was separated from him completely to form evil Buu, and when defeated, evil Buu's spirit of life force is incarnated in a little kid named Uub. if we consider picolo's case, the only way to get the evil back is to become one with Uub, otherwise nothing will be triggered because there is no evil in him to be triggered in the first place.